# calculate movement based on time

Tags: javascript, math

So I am workng on a little project, mostly to help me learn better javascript and I'm having a little problem. I can do animations just fine, but my problem is.. I'm trying to figure out the math necessary to calculate the amount of change in pixels to move each step of the animation. So say my div is 450px wide and I'm saying animate({ width : 600, duration : 2000 }). that leaves 150px of total movement, but how much movement to I do for each frame if I'm calling my setTimeout function every 3 milliseconds. I know the solution is probably simple but for some reason, maybe just because I have been beating my head on a wall for while writing this whole thing and now I can't think enough to figure it out. I can show code examples if anyone needs. Thank you for the help in advance. 
As per request here is the code I have so far to do the animation...

```
animate : function(params, duration) {
    if(!params) {
        return this;
    } else {
        this.current = this._defCurrent;
        console.log(this.current);
        var time = (duration) ? duration : this.slow;
        var target;
        for(var index in params) {
            if(index == 'queue') {
                if(params[index]){
                    this.animQueue = true;
                } else {
                    this.animQueue = false;
                }
            } else {
                var current = parseFloat(this.getStyle(index));
                if(current < params[index]) {
                    target = params[index] - current;
                    animDirection = '+';
                } else {
                    target = current - params[index];
                    animDirection = '-';
                }
                totalMovement = target / time;
                animObj = {type : index, target : target, move : totalMovement, direction : animDirection, duration : time};
                this.setAnimQueue(animObj);
            }
        }
    }
    this.setTheTimeout();
},
setAnimQueue : function(obj) {
    var that = this;
    for(var i = 0, amt = (obj.duration * this.fps); i < amt; i++) {
        var fun = this.wrapFunction(that.doAnim, this, [obj.type, obj.move, obj.direction]);
        this.queue.push(fun);
    }
},
setTheTimeout : function() {
    var that = this;
    this.interValAmt = setInterval(function() {
        that.deQueue()
    }, this.fps);
},
doAnim : function(type, amount, direction) {
    var totalAmount = eval(parseFloat(this[type]()) + direction + amount);
    if(this.elem.style[this.toCamelCase(type)]) {
        this[type](totalAmount);
    } else {
        this[type](totalAmount)
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: We would like to please see what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have distance, and you have duration. Dividing them gives speed. Simply multiply the speed by the time increment to get the distance increment.

Comment: ok, so I would take 150 / 2000 which gives .075 so I would multiply that by 3 (for the amount of milliseconds in between calling the animate) to get a total of .225px of movement per movement, 2000 times? then I run the animation how many times to get the 150, 2000 / 3?

Comment: using the above formula, I'm saying totalMovement = (target / time) * this.fps; ... (this.fps = 3), then in setAminQueue I am saying (for var i = 0, amt = (obj.duration / this.fps); i < amt; i++). but that seems to make the animation last way too long... i set obj.duration to 2000, which is what time is as well and the animation lasted 4 seconds or 4000

Comment: How certain are you that it's being called every 3ms?

Comment: I can put a console.log in the deQueue method, but it logs so fast it's hard to say that it is exactly every 3 milliseconds. I know that the class method fps : 3, so when calling setInterval and passing this.fps should be saying call it every 3 milliseconds

Comment: I think I know why, I am animating 2 things at once, the width and the height so in theory the animation for each one is lasting the right amount of time, but the queue calls then one at a time and alternates between the two, thereby making the animation last twice as long. Would a good work around be to multiply the amount of movement by the number of things being animated to speed it up?

Comment: The best way would be to use the wall clock instead of assuming that the timing is perfect.

Comment: So in deQueue I have a console.log(new Date().getTime()) and it seems to be logging every 5-10 milliseconds pretty randomly. Is that just a javascript thing, it can't actually run every 3 milliseconds due to processor cycles? what would be the best interval I could run to make this completely smooth?